# Base Version of Mocked Protected Method Is Being Executed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm writing a test, using Moq, to verify parameters on a protected method.  I'm setting up the protected method as follows:

```
RedirectResult expectedResult = new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");

mockController.Protected()
    .Setup<ActionResult>(
        "InternalBuyerProfilePost",
        It.IsAny<int>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<IList<PermissionArea>>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<IList<int>>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<IList<int>>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<IList<int>>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<int?>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<int?>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<int?>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<int?>())
    .Returns(expectedResult);
```

Actual method sig looks like:

```
protected virtual ActionResult InternalBuyerProfilePost(
    int centralUserInt, IList<PermissionArea> PermissionAreas,
    IList<int> AccessiblePropertyGroups, IList<int> AccessibleBuyers, IList<int> AccessibleClients,
    int? assignableCompanyInt, int? rbProperties, int? rbContacts, int? rbClients)
```

`InternalBuyerProfilePost` is called by:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuyerProfile(int userInt, IList<PermissionArea> PermissionAreas,
                                 IList<int> AccessiblePropertyGroups, IList<int> AccessibleBuyers,
                                 int? assignableCompanyInt, int? rbStations, int? rbContacts)
{
    return InternalBuyerProfilePost(userInt, PermissionAreas, AccessiblePropertyGroups, 
                                    AccessibleBuyers, null, assignableCompanyInt, rbStations, 
                                    rbContacts, null);
}
```

And passes null into `AccessibleClients` and `rbClients`.  However, when I call `BuyerProfile`, the base version of `InternalBuyerProfilePost` is executed rather than the mocked version.  I'm not sure what's going on here.  Since my setup uses nothing but the `It/ItExpr` I would think it should be capturing all executions, but that's apparently not the case.  Types defined in the setup match the method parameters of the mocked method.  I don't have any idea why this is giving me trouble.

Thanks for your helps!  Let me know if you'd like to see anything else.

Comment: Did you set the `Callbase` property to `true` on your mock object?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your mockController's InternalBuyerProfilePost method is not only declared as protected but also **overrides** the base class's InternalBuyerProfilePost method.  Otherwise, it will, by default, shadow the method instead of override it, which would lead to the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

In your first argument you have `It` instead of `ItExpr`. If `It.IsAny<int>()` is *called* (as opposed to represented in an expression tree), it returns `0`. Maybe you only `Setup` the case where the first argument is zero? Try using `ItExpr` instead.

If you change `mockController` to have mock behavior `Strict`, you will be notified if you invoke someting that was not properly `Setup`.